# Trying to multiply lists together in haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been studying Haskell, since my teacher forced us to.
As an exercise, we'll try writing up a solution to approximate sin(x) function using its Maclaurin series only up to the 30th term.

I thought up of using lists for the alternating series of 1 and -1, the x raised to an odd number, and the factorial of odd numbers. Then, I'll multiply the first two lists and divide the last. Until now I only have written this:

```
oddl = [1,3..]
powerl x = map (x^) oddl
factorial 0 = 1
factorial x = factorial (x - 1) * x
factl = map factorial oddl
alterl = scanl (*) (-1) [-1,-1..]
sined x = zipWith (*) (powerl x) alterl
sinex x = zipWith (/) sined factl
sinf x = foldl (+) (take 30 (sinex x))
```

Then in `ghci`, I'll enter `sinf 3.14` but before I can enter it after loading I get this:

```
exert.hs:31:8:
    No instance for (Enum t0)
      arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘1, 3 .. ’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include oddl :: [t0] (bound at exert.hs:31:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance forall (k :: BOX) (s :: k). Enum (Data.Proxy.Proxy s)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Proxy’
      instance Integral a => Enum (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Enum Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
      ...plus 8 others
    In the expression: [1, 3 .. ]
    In an equation for ‘oddl’: oddl = [1, 3 .. ]

exert.hs:31:9:
    No instance for (Num t0) arising from the literal ‘1’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include oddl :: [t0] (bound at exert.hs:31:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
      instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: 1
    In the expression: [1, 3 .. ]
    In an equation for ‘oddl’: oddl = [1, 3 .. ]

exert.hs:32:18:
    Could not deduce (Integral t0) arising from a use of ‘^’
    from the context (Num b)
      bound by the inferred type of powerl :: Num b => b -> [b]
      at exert.hs:32:1-24
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(x ^)’
    In the expression: map (x ^) oddl
    In an equation for ‘powerl’: powerl x = map (x ^) oddl

exert.hs:35:13:
    No instance for (Eq t0) arising from a use of ‘factorial’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include factl :: [t0] (bound at exert.hs:35:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Either a b)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
      instance forall (k :: BOX) (s :: k). Eq (Data.Proxy.Proxy s)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Proxy’
      instance (GHC.Arr.Ix i, Eq e) => Eq (GHC.Arr.Array i e)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Arr’
      ...plus 28 others
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘factorial’
    In the expression: map factorial oddl
    In an equation for ‘factl’: factl = map factorial oddl

exert.hs:38:23:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[t0]’
                with actual type ‘Integer -> [Integer]’
    Relevant bindings include
      sinex :: t -> [t0] (bound at exert.hs:38:1)
    Probable cause: ‘sined’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of ‘zipWith’, namely ‘sined’
    In the expression: zipWith (/) sined factl

exert.hs:39:16:
    Could not deduce (Num [t0]) arising from a use of ‘+’
    from the context (Foldable t)
      bound by the inferred type of
               sinf :: Foldable t => t1 -> t [t0] -> [t0]
      at exert.hs:39:1-38
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      sinf :: t1 -> t [t0] -> [t0] (bound at exert.hs:39:1)
    In the first argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘(+)’
    In the expression: foldl (+) (take 30 (sinex x))
    In an equation for ‘sinf’: sinf x = foldl (+) (take 30 (sinex x))
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

so much messages. wow. 
I don't have any clue on what I have been doing wrong nor even know where to start reading the message.
May anyone shed light on this? Actually as a beginner, I am curious on how is it wrong in Haskell and what's preventing it to work.

**EDIT: After adding type signatures and a missing argument.**

```
oddl :: [Integer]
oddl = [1,3..]
powerl :: Integer -> [Integer]
powerl x = map (x^) oddl
factorial 0 = 1
factorial x = factorial (x - 1) * x
factl :: [Integer]
factl = map factorial oddl
alterl = scanl (*) (-1) [-1,-1..]
sined x = zipWith (*) (powerl x) alterl
sinex x = zipWith (/) (sined x) factl
sinf x = foldl (+) (take 30 (sinex x))
```

Now I get a shorter error:

```
exert.hs:41:19:
    No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of ‘/’
    In the first argument of ‘zipWith’, namely ‘(/)’
    In the expression: zipWith (/) (sined x) factl
    In an equation for ‘sinex’: sinex x = zipWith (/) (sined x) factl

exert.hs:42:16:
    Could not deduce (Num [Integer]) arising from a use of ‘+’
    from the context (Foldable t)
      bound by the inferred type of
               sinf :: Foldable t => Integer -> t [Integer] -> [Integer]
      at exert.hs:42:1-38
    In the first argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘(+)’
    In the expression: foldl (+) (take 30 (sinex x))
    In an equation for ‘sinf’: sinf x = foldl (+) (take 30 (sinex x))
```

Comment: **Always write out type signatures**. (That probably won't fix your problem, but it will certainly do a great deal to make the error messages less cryptic.)

Comment: I probably not suppose to ask this here, but what exactly are type signatures? Is that that one line with ":: "?

Comment: @user3076623 Yes, exactly.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, It did became less cryptic but now it's searching for "Fractional Integer".

Comment: You wrote a couple type signatures, but you need to write all of them.

Comment: The second error is with `foldl` and not with numeric types. Look up `foldl` again, pay attention to what kind of arguments it expects.

Comment: @n.m. Could you enlighten me about what to write, I think trying to write all types as Integer wouldn't work.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, it makes little sense to take a sine of an integer argument and expect an integer result. You need to have a `Double` in there at some point.

Comment: Not relevant but `alterl = iterate negate 1` feels more concise

Comment: @RegisKuckaertz I think `alterl = cycle [1,-1]` is even clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numerics in Haskell have a lot to do with types and type inference, so they can be tricky for beginners. You're not allowed to divide integers at all with the `/` operator (there is `` `div` `` for truncating integer division).  What makes a constant an integer can also be rather tricky, as it depends on how it is used (later!)<sup>1</sup>.  But the main thing you need to know about is the `fromIntegral` function, which casts from an integer into any other numeric type.

```
ghci> let x = 10 :: Integer
ghci> x / 5
<interactive>:6:1: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of ‘/’
    • In the expression: x / 5
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = x / 5
ghci> fromIntegral x / 5
2.0
```

And *@leftroundabout*'s comment is absolutely right!  Type inference is lovely but if you let it run wild it can be very confusing; rein it in with type signatures.

---

<sup>1</sup>Here's one thing that went wrong, if you are interested. Maybe it will help with understanding how types and numbers interact.

`(^)` takes an integer (technically any "`Integral`" type, which defaults to `Integer` if there is nothing else to make the decision) as its right argument, so we know from

```
powerl x = map (x^) oddl
```

that `oddl` must be a list of integers.  `(*)` returns the same type as its arguments (which must be the same type), so we know from

```
factorial x = factorial (x - 1) * x
```

that `factorial` returns the same type as its argument, and thus

```
factl = map factorial oddl
```

must also be a list of integers.  Then we have

```
sinex x = zipWith (/) sined factl
```

which is now giving integers as an argument to `(/)`, which is not legal.

Comment: But fromIntegral only applies to a single value, right?

Comment: @user3076623, yeah, but it's a regular function, so you can `map` it.  I'd probably rather make a little helper though `divInts x y = fromIntegral x / fromIntegral y` to do your zipping with.

Comment: So it's like "sined x = map (fromIntegral) (zipWith (*) (powerl x) alterl)"?

Comment: @user3076623, looks right to me  *(modulo superfluous parens around `fromIntegral`)*

Comment: actually, your suggestion works! The first one, I mean.

Answer (score 2):

After your edits, looking at the first error:

```
No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of ‘/’
```

The type of `(/)` is:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

So it takes two values of type `a`, which must be `Fractional`, and returns a result of the same type `a`. `Integer` is not `Fractional`—there are integer division functions `div` and `quot` (and their remainder counterparts, `mod` and `rem`), but that’s not what you want here, because you want a fractional result. The solution is to convert the integer argument to a fractional type such as `Double` using `fromIntegral`:

```
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b

fromIntegral (x :: Integer) :: Double  -- or ‘… :: Float’
```

So for example you could write `sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)` to get the mean of a list of `Double`.

The second error:

```
Could not deduce (Num [Integer]) arising from a use of ‘+’
```

Arises from this expression:

```
foldl (+) (take 30 (sinex x))
```

`foldl` takes three arguments: the reducing function, the starting value, and the input container; you’re trying to pass the container as the starting value, so `foldl` tries to call `+` on a list of integers, which is not defined. You might want `foldl (+) 0` or `sum` there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more reasonable way to write it all:

```
sinf :: Double -> Double
sinf x = sum $ take 30
           [ sign * power / fact
           | (sign, power, fact) <- zip3
               (iterate negate 1)
               (oddEntries $ iterate (*x) 1)
               (oddEntries factorials) ]
 where factorials :: [Double]
       factorials = scanl (*) 1 [1..]

oddEntries :: [a] -> [a]
oddEntries (_:x:xs) = x : oddEntries xs
oddEntries _ = []
```

Note that I didn't need any `fromIntegral`, because I declared the list of factorials as `Double`. That's of course not precise, but it doesn't matter in this application (the error is anyway dominated by the truncation of the series) and it's much more efficient for big numbers than converting from `Integer`.

Also I avoided the `^` operator, which is quite wasteful in this case: the intermediate results of the multiplication are anyways needed in the Maclaurin series, so better also do this with iterated multiplication!

Incidentally, you can then also omit the local binding and just write it all inline:

```
sinf :: Double -> Double
sinf x = sum $ take 30
           [ sign * power / fact
           | (sign, power, fact) <- zip3
               (iterate negate 1)
               (oddEntries $ iterate (*x) 1)
               (oddEntries $ scanl (*) 1 [1..]) ]
```

Here the typechecker automatically does the right thing and chooses the type `Double` for the list of factorials (as well as the list of signs), because the context requires `Double`. (But it can be a good idea to nevertheless give it a local name and signature, for the sake of readability.)

---

```
$ ghci wtmpf-file3770.hs 
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghc/ghci.conf
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( wtmpf-file3770.hs, interpreted )
Ok, 1 module loaded.
*Main> :m +Graphics.Dynamic.Plot.R2 
*Main Graphics.Dynamic.Plot.R2> plotWindow [legendName "sin" $ continFnPlot sin, legendName "sinf" $ continFnPlot sinf]
```

[image: plot of the truncate-maclaurin sine]

In practice, you'd only use the Maclaurin series in the small range around zero, and exploit the periodicity for defining the function on the remainder of the real axis:

```
sinf :: Double -> Double
sinf x = sum $ take 30
           [ sign * power / fact
           | (sign, power, fact) <- zip3
               (iterate negate 1)
               (oddEntries $ iterate (*x') 1)
               (oddEntries factorials) ]
 where factorials :: [Double]
       factorials = scanl (*) 1 [1..]
       x' = x - 2*pi*fromIntegral (round $ x/(2*pi))
```

[image: trunctation error of Maclauring fixed by exploiting periodicity]